# Extract value from css jquery extractor and json extractor

Tags: jquery

how to Extract values from below respone using css jquery extractor.
means i need (these values 802028381,802028385,802028387,802028389).
how can i do can u pls suggest me,

```
                            <select name=listing_variation_id>
                                <option value="" selected>
                                    Size
                                </option>
                                802028381
                                    XS
                                </option>
                                <option value="802028385">
                                    S
                                </option>
                                <option value="802028387">
                                    M
                                </option>
                                <option value="802028389">
                                    L
                                </option>
                                   </option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

Comment: You can use `map()` to build an array from the attributes of a collection of elements: http://api.jquery.com/map. Also note that the HTML is invalid; you appear to be missing the second opening `<option>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` to loop thru each option and get their value `attr`

```js
var result = $('[name="listing_variation_id"]>option:not(:eq(0))').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('value');
}).get();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="listing_variation_id">
  <option value="selected">
    Size
  </option>
  <option value="802028381">
    XS
  </option>
  <option value="802028385">
    S
  </option>
  <option value="802028387">
    M
  </option>
  <option value="802028389">
    L
  </option>

</select>
```

Comment: what is the css jquery expression i need to add in jmeter to get values

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Loop and get value with not selector.

```js
var arr = [];
$("select > option:not(:first)").each(function(index, element) {
  arr.push($(this).val());
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name=listing_variation_id>
  <option value="" selected>
    Size
  </option>
  <option value="802028381">
    XS
  </option>
  <option value="802028385">
    S
  </option>
  <option value="802028387">
    M
  </option>
  <option value="802028389">
    L
  </option>
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: what is the css jquery expression i need to add in jmeter to get values

Comment: What do you mean by css jquery expression i didn't understand? what is your expected out put?

Comment: ur answer is correct shree but am using JMETER TOOL in that i need to add css jquery expression soo

Comment: can u pls tell the css jquery expression to add in my tool i had gone through blazmeter info but didnt get any idea vil u please